# Does Apple's Numbers support 3rd party plugins / data providers / formulas / functions?

Tags: numbers, plugins

Numbers has the ability to pull in prices for various [stocks](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH26371) and [currencies](https://support.apple.com/en-au/HT207109). However, I am after the ability for it to pull in prices for various cryptocurrencies, [not just BTC](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8031990), such as [Cryptofinance](https://jbuty.com/how-to-get-crypto-currencies-rates-and-more-in-google-sheet-1a57e571bc14) does for Google Sheets.

As Numbers doesn't currently offer that functionality, my question is: **Does Numbers support the ability to be extended with plugins? Such that one can create/use custom-made formulas/functions.**

It seems all the major competitors to Numbers offer such functionality:

- [Google Sheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions)
- [Microsoft Excel](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-custom-functions-in-Excel-2F06C10B-3622-40D6-A1B2-B6748AE8231F)
- [LibreOffice Calc](https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/User-Defined_Functions)

Crossposted on the [Apple Discussions community](https://discussions.apple.com/message/33481610).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No.**

According to [this outdated post](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/1857310?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) the answer is no. I also doubt Apple would add this feature.

> There is no "plug-in" architecture yet for Numbers. the '09 version
>   does have some basic scripting ability it looks like. But I haven't
>   gotten it to work yet. Waiting for someone that knows more than me to
>   post some examples.

You can make a feature request [here](https://www.apple.com/feedback/)

**Although not plugins per se, Numbers (and the entire iWork suite) [does have](https://iworkautomation.com/numbers/script-menu.html) a library for AppleScript.**